# spring securit3.x y integration with wicket 6.7.0

Tags: spring-security, wicket

I am new to wicket and SpringSecurity. I configured the spring security as follows.

```
<http create-session="never" auto-config="true">
    <remember-me />
    <http-basic />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
    <!-- <form-login login-page="/admin"/> <logout invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/admin" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/> -->
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"></authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

I have extended the AuthenticatedWebSession doing the authentication in my extended class.

My Questions :

1. How can I configure for form based Authentication.
2. How can I configure for Session Management.
3. How can I configure for Single Sign in per user (Here if the user try to login with same user I want invalidate the session of the previous logged in user. )
4. Need reference manual on Spring Security Integration with Wicket.

Please also let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at the following working example on Wicket / Spring-Security integration on github: https://github.com/thombergs/wicket-spring-security-example.

Your questions are a little vague for a helpful answer, so I'd suggest yoiu have a look at the example on github and ask again if you have any problems.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom. I gone through the example it helps a lot.

Comment: Hi Tom I post one more issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720617/concurrency-control-configurarion-using-spring-security-in-wicket-6-7-0 plz once help me on that.